# Dynamics AX 2009 AIF Tables

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics, aif

**Background**

I have an issue where roughly once a month the AIFQueueManager table is populated with ~150 records which relate to messages which had been sent to AX (where they "successfully failed"; i.e. errorred due to violation of business rules, but returned an exception as expected) over 6 months ago.

---

**Question**

What tables are involved in the AIF inbound message process / what order to events occur in?  e.g. XML file is picked up and recorded in the AifDocumentLog, data's extracted and added to the AifQueueManager and AifGatewayQueue tables, records from here are then inserted in the AifMessageLog, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 4 main **AIF** classes, I will be talking about the inbound only, and focusing on the included file system adapter and flat XML files.  I hope this makes things a little less hazy.

1. `AIFGatewayReceiveService` - Uses adapters/channels to read messages **in** from different sources, and dumps them in the AifGatewayQueue table
2. `AIFInboundProcessingService` - This processes the AifGatewayQueue table data and sends to the Ax[Document] classes
3. `AIFOutboundProcessingService` - This is the inverse of #2. It creates XMLs with relevent metadata
4. `AIFGatewaySendService` - This is the inverse of #1, where it uses adapters/channels to send messages **out** to different locations from the AifGatewayQueue

---

**For #1**

So #1 basically fills the `AifGatewayQueue`, which is just a queue of work.  It loops through all of your channels and then finds the relevant adapter by ClassId.  The adapters are classes that implement `AifIntegrationAdapter` and `AifReceiveAdapter` if you wanted to make your own custom one.  When it loops over the different channels, it then loops over each "message" and tries to receive it into the queue.

If it can't process the file for some reason, it catches exceptions and throws them in the `SysExceptionTable` [Basic>Periodic>Application Integration Framework>Exceptions].  These messages are scraped from the infolog, and the messages are generated mostly from the receive adaptor, which would be `AifFileSystemReceiveAdapter` for my example.

---

**For #2**

So #2 is processing the inbound messages sitting in the queue (ready/inprocess).  The `AifRequestProcessor\processServiceRequest` does the work.

From this method, it will call:

- Various calls to `Classes\AifMessageManager`, which puts records in the `AifMessageLog` and the `AifDocumentLog`.
- This **key** line: `responseMessage = AifRequestProcessor::executeServiceOperation(message, endpointActionPolicy);` which actually does the operation against the Ax[Document] classes by eventually getting to `AifDispatcher::callServiceMethod(...)`
- It gets the return XML and packages that into an AifMessage called `responseMessage` and returns that where it may be logged.  It also takes that return value, and if there is a response channel, it submits that back into the AifGatewayQueue

---

`AifQueueManager` is actually cleared and populated on the fly by calling `AifQueueManager::createQueueManagerData();`.